# Best way to prepare array by keys without foreach with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function that returns a new array by keys mask from main array of properties.

It's like:

*Client*

```
$preparedParams = $request->prepareParams([
    'name',
    'price',
    'description',
    'tags',
], $request->params());
```

*$request->params()* - return array like below

```
[
    'name' => 'iPhone',
    'price' => 123,
    'description' => 'Some desc',
    'action' => 'add',
    'page' => 'product',
    'etc...' => '...',
]
```

*Need for*

```
$newProduct = new ModelProduct();
$newProduct->set($preparedParams);
$newProduct->save();
```

**An easier solution**

```
public function prepareParams(array $keys, array $values): array
{
    $result = [];
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $result[$key] = $values[$key] ?? null;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Means that need include all params from keys mask including NULLs too

**Second solution (may better?)**

I've tried to do it without foreach, but not sure that the best way to do it.

```
public function prepareParams(array $keys, array $values): array
{
    return array_merge(
        $filledByKeys = array_fill_keys($keys, null),
        array_intersect_key($values, $filledByKeys)
    );
}
```

As you can see we create empty array with keys (it's first argument for merge). Then used intersect by key to get array that contains props from values (it's second argument for merge). And merged it with NULL keys.

But may you show better way for it?

Thank you!

Comment: `foreach` is highly optimised, and is sometimes faster than array functions. If your code with `foreach` does what you need, use it. I don't see what you're asking for here.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular understood you. Thank you for this answer! Just trying to find pretty solution with array functions or so. But now I'll use foreach for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?
The loop is "hidden" by array_map ;)

edit: Oh... that's slightly wrong.. I'll correct
edit2: updated to requirements.

```
$keys = [
    'name',
    'price',
    'description',
    'tags',
];

$src = [
    'name' => 'iPhone',
    'price' => 123,
    'description' => 'Some desc',
    'action' => 'add',
    'page' => 'product',
    'etc...' => '...',
];

$result = [];
array_map(function($key, $key2, $val) use (&$result) {
    if ($key == $key2) {
        $result[ $key ] = $val;
    }
    elseif($key != null) {
        $result[ $key ] = null;
    }
}, $keys, array_keys($src), array_values($src));

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "iPhone"
  ["price"]=>
  int(123)
  ["description"]=>
  string(9) "Some desc"
  ["tags"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: Thank you with reply. I've tried do it with map but it' don't work for me. Because `[tags] => add` but wait for `[tags] => NULL`. tags missing in src and will return null for tag in this case

Comment: I've updated the code...